# javascript regex always return false?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know it's newbie question but i don't know how to get over with it.
Match() string using regex always returning false. Values are from autcomplete.

```
    var str = '1 - Hello';
    var pattern = /^[\d]\s-\s[a-z]/;
    if(str.match(pattern))
    {
        alert('Hell Yeah');
    }
    else
        alert('noooooooo');
```

I don't know what i am missing here. But in [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/tS9pN4/1) it's working.

*My answer* : **`/\d+ - \w+/i`**

**Thanks for Responses. Voted for Close.**

Comment: Note that in your test you wrote `hello`, not `Hello`.

Comment: Also note that `[\d]` is precisely the same as `\d` without the `[ ]`.

Comment: In other words, `var pattern = /^\d\s-\s[a-z]/i;` should do.

Comment: @Matthijs: [`[A-z]` is treacherous](https://regex101.com/r/tS9pN4/2). See [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew even I'm still learning every day, nice one, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following change I have made based on the regex test you conducted.

```
var str = '1 - Hello'; 
var pattern = /^\d\s-\s[a-z]/i;
 //change made above
if(str.match(pattern)) 
{ 
alert('Hell Yeah'); 
} 
else 
alert('noooooooo');
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allowing lower case letters, try:

`var pattern = /^[\d]\s-\s[a-zA-Z]/;`

This still only matches the first letter of 'Hello', if you want to match the whole word it'll be:

`var pattern = /^[\d]\s-\s[a-zA-Z]+/;`

Comment: Still not working.  I don't care what is after `/^[\d]\s-\s[a-z]`. Pattern should be **number whitespace hyphen(-) whitespace characters**.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Please clarify your question then - if you don't care what's after the `- `, why are you looking for `[a-z]`?

Comment: `/\d\s-\s/` / `/^\d\s-\s/` should do the trick then?

https://regex101.com/r/jT0mC9/1

(add ^ at the beginning if you only want matches at the start)